# Crud operations in single API vs different API'S

Tags: java, rest, crud

While building API's, we use different approaches for CRUD operations. Sometimes we build single API that will handle insert, update and delete together. Sometimes we build different API'S that handles each operations separately say insert separate API, update separate API and delete separate API. I want to know which is the best approach to be followed. And if so why. Any documents proving the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Website Link - [Click here to visit and more details](https://dev.to/decipherzonesoft/types-of-apis-what-are-apis-different-types-of-apis-3mjm)

Article Author -  Mahipal Nehra  [His LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/in/mahipal-nehra-80254928/)

> **Types of APIs**
>
> The classification of APIs can be done on three parameters which are
>   listed as follows:
>
> **Ownership types of Web APIs**
>
> On Ownership level there are four main types of APIs:
>
> **Open APIs**: These APIs are publicly available to use like Oauth APIs from Google and there is no restriction to use them. Hence, they
>   are also known as Public APIs.
>
> **Partner APIs**: Specific rights or licenses in order to access this type of API because they are not available to the public. Usually,
>   these kinds of APIs are associated with paid services
>
> **Internal APIs:** The APIs that are developed by companies to use into their internal systems so that they can enhance the productivity
>   of development teams where one team can use services from another
>   project of the company is called Internal APIs. These APIs are also
>   known as Private APIs.
>
> **Composite API**s: Both processes and composite APIS are a sequence of tasks but composite APIs combines different data and service APIs.
>   It is a sequence of tasks that run synchronously as a result of the
>   execution where the result of triggering of a Composite API is the
>   result of the execution and not the request that will contain the
>   result of the execution at the request of a task. Its main usage is to
>   speed up the process of execution and improve the performance of the
>   listeners in the web interfaces.
>
> **Communication level of APIs**
>
> **High-Level APIs**
>
> High-level APIs are those that we use generally in REST form where
>   programmers have a high level of abstraction and they are only
>   concerned about performing a limited functionality.
>
> **Low-Level APIs** Low-level APIs have a lower level of abstraction hence they are most detailed, which allows the programmer to
>   manipulate functions within an application module or within hardware
>   at a granular level. Usually, Low-level APIs are used in sending the
>   real-time video or media feed in response to a trigger like Vulkan
>   APIs.
>
> **Web service APIs** In web service APIs the classification is done on the type of communication and behavioural approach used in building
>   APIs:
>
> *SOAP
>
> *XML-RPC
>
> *JSON-RPC
>
> *REST
>
> Web service APIs are small applications that use URLs or web addresses
>   on the internet to provide their services to desktop, mobile, web
>   applications and others.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way, at least according to [here](https://restfulapi.net/rest-api-design-tutorial-with-example/) is to have multiple API endpoints (I am assuming that this is what you mean when you say *different API's*) and distinguish between them by using the various HTTP methods available.

For instance:

- [HTTP GET] `/product`: To read all the available products in the DB
- [HTTP GET] `/product/123`: The get specifically information on product 123.
- [HTTP POST] `/product`: To create a new product through the API.
- [HTTP PUT] `/product/123`: To update an existing product through the API.
- [HTTP DELETE] `/product/123`: To delete product 123 through the API.

Although the routes all look similar, these will in turn be mapped to various methods within your controller class which perform the necessary task accordingly.